# How can I model an ERD with relationships that include "this or that but not both" and "this and that"?

Tags: database-design, erd

I am having trouble drawing a entity-relationship diagram (ERD) and I wanted to ask for any guidance on what I am doing wrong.

**Busines rules**

The descriptions of the assignment and of the business domain of relevance are:

> Revise the E-R data model you created in part A to create a new E-R data model based on the fact that students, faculty, alumni, and mentors are all a PERSON. Use the IE Crow’s Foot E-R model for your E-R diagrams. Justify the decisions you make regarding minimum and maximum cardinality. Note that:
>
> - A person may be a current student, an alumnus, or both because Highline University does have alumni return for further study.
> - A person may be a faculty member or a mentor, but not both.
> - A person may be a faculty member and an alumnus.
> - A person may be a mentor and an alumnus.
> - A current student cannot be a mentor.
> - Each mentor may be an alumnus, but mentors are not required to be alumni.
> - Alumni cannot, of course, be required to become mentors.

**My current considerations**

From my reading I believe the format should be in a supertype/subtype layout. The problem is, the examples I see only have two subtypes for each supertype. So does the question want me to draw out four separate supertype PERSON entities with two choices of subtypes under them?

**The ERD I have drawn so far**

I have a diagram started but it looks wrong to me in every way. It is displayed below:

[image]

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can someone be both a faculty member and student?